# 401 When passing the token using graphic onenote api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft graph so this might be a dumb question. 
So I am writing a command line application trying to update a page in our team onenote. (enterprise onenote)
Here is the code I got work getting the token.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=my_client_Id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=Some_uri&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&scope=Notes.ReadWrite.All

I got the token as strCode and trying to retrieve all the notes under this account by these codes:

```
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })       
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, @"/pages");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strCode);

        using (var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
            string responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```

And in the response data I got
"{   \"error\": {     \"code\": \"InvalidAuthenticationToken\",     \"message\": \"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105\",     \"innerError\": {       \"request-id\": \"*********************",       \"date\": \"2017-06-08T18:25:06\"     }   } }"

Any idea how to fix this..?

Comment: Take a look at http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved . 
I need to convert the authentication code into a "real" access token.. 
The one that I got is not an access token.